# Prefix expression to evaluate multiple expressions simultaneously

Tags: java, expression

```
private class InputListener implements ActionListener
    {
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
      {
         Stack<Integer> operandStack = new Stack<Integer>();
         Stack<Character> operatorStack = new Stack<Character>();

         String input = inputTextField.getText();

         StringTokenizer strToken = new StringTokenizer(input, " ", false);


         while (strToken.hasMoreTokens())
         {
             String i = strToken.nextToken();
             int operand;
             char operator;

             try
             {
                 operand = Integer.parseInt(i);
                 operandStack.push(operand);
             }
             catch (NumberFormatException nfe)
             {
                 operator = i.charAt(0);
                 operatorStack.push(operator);
             }
          }
          int result = sum (operandStack, operatorStack);
          resultTextField.setText(Integer.toString(result));
       }
```

My prefix expression code will only evaluate one expression at a time (i.e. + 3 1). I want it to evaluate multiple expressions in one user-input expression (i.e. * + 16 4 + 3 1). How can I edit the code provided to make it evaluate multiple expressions? Thank you for your help.

Comment: What is method `sum` doing?

Comment: @isnot2bad The sum method calculates the sum or the product of the operands. I'm using if...else if statements in the sum method to calculate. For example: if(operator == '+'){ operand1 = operandStack.pop(); operand2 = operandStack.pop(); result = operand2 + operand1; }. How can I edit the code to make it evaluate multiple expressions at once?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To simply make your program do a bit more you can use a loop to keep operating on the `operandStack` and pushing the result of the previous result to the stack. I left my `println` statements in so you can see what its doing. Also I modified your method so it can sit inside a standalone `main` method.

You should look into the Shunting-yard algorithm, its quite fun to implement and it is somewhat like what your doing here. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shunting-yard_algorithm

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Stack<Integer> operandStack = new Stack<Integer>();
    Stack<Character> operatorStack = new Stack<Character>();

    String input = "12 + 13 - 4";

    StringTokenizer strToken = new StringTokenizer(input, " ", false);

    while (strToken.hasMoreTokens()) {
        String i = strToken.nextToken();
        int operand;
        char operator;

        try {
            operand = Integer.parseInt(i);
            operandStack.push(operand);
        } catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {
            operator = i.charAt(0);
            operatorStack.push(operator);
        }
    }

    // loop until there is only 1 item left in the operandStack, this 1 item left is the result
    while(operandStack.size() > 1) {
        // some debugging println
        System.out.println("Operate\n\tbefore");
        System.out.println("\t"+operandStack);
        System.out.println("\t"+operatorStack);

        // perform the operations on the stack and push the result back onto the operandStack
        operandStack.push(operate(operandStack, operatorStack));

        System.out.println("\tafter");
        System.out.println("\t"+operandStack);
        System.out.println("\t"+operatorStack);
    }

    System.out.println("Result is: " + operandStack.peek());
}

/**
 * Performs math operations and returns the result. Pops 2 items off the operandStack and 1 off the operator stack. 
 * @param operandStack
 * @param operatorStack
 * @return
 */
private static int operate(Stack<Integer> operandStack, Stack<Character> operatorStack) {
    char op = operatorStack.pop();
    Integer a = operandStack.pop();
    Integer b = operandStack.pop();
    switch(op) {
        case '-':
            return b - a;
        case '+':
            return a + b;
        default:
            throw new IllegalStateException("Unknown operator '"+op+"'");
    }
}
```

---

I left the `operate` method (previously called `sum`) as close to what you had it as possible, however I think that your code could be improved by simply passing 2 integers and a operator to the function. Making the function alter your stacks isnt a great thing and could lead to confusing problems.

Consider making your method signature this instead:

```
private static int operate(Integer a, Integer b, char operator) {
    switch(operator) {
        case '-':
            return b - a;
        case '+':
            return a + b;
        default:
            throw new IllegalStateException("Unknown operator '"+operator+"'");
    }
}
```

and then popping from the stack and passing those to the method. Keeping your stack altering code all in one place.

```
operandStack.push(operate(operandStack.pop(), operandStack.pop(), operatorStack.pop()));
```

Comment: Thanks ug_. I'm now implementing your code, but not sure where to put the last line of code you gave me: operandStack.push(operate(operandStack.pop(), operandStack.pop(), operatorStack.pop()));. Where do I implement it?

Comment: @Jeremy it would be in place of `operandStack.push(operate(operandStack, operatorStack));` inside the while loop.

Comment: Also I need to use the resultTextField.setText(); statement to store the result in the GUI but you removed it. How do I use it now?

Comment: @Jeremy add it back in... the same way you were before.

Comment: I added it back in and it works by replacing 'result' with 'operandStack.peek()', but now there's another problem; it's not calculating correctly with more than one operator. Prefix expression * + 16 4 + 3 1 should equal 80 but it comes to 128. How do I correct this?

Comment: @Jeremy I dont know how that could come out to 80. Also im not sure what format the expression `* + 16 4 + 3 1` is suppose to be but thats not valid math. View the output which I left in and see why its not working as intended.

Comment: Prefix expression, * + 16 4 + 3 1, is calculated as follows: (16 + 4) * (3 + 1). Thanks for all your help, ug_, I'll work with it and try to resolve it, I'll maybe even ask another question here to get help.